# Query com Hibernate usando Like e Where

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Beleza Galera ? Então estou fazendo uma query com hibernate, que é a seguinte:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.filial =:filial AND c.ativo =:ativo AND c.tipoCliente =:tipoCliente AND c.cnpj_cpf LIKE :cnpj_cpf_formatado OR  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( c.cnpj_cpf, '.', '' ),'/',''),'-','') LIKE  :cnpj_cpf OR c.razaoSocialNome LIKE :razaoSocialNome", Cliente.class)
            .setParameter("razaoSocialNome", "%" + texto.toUpperCase() + "%")
            .setParameter("cnpj_cpf", "%" + texto.toUpperCase() + "%")
            .setParameter("cnpj_cpf_formatado", "%" + texto.toUpperCase() + "%")
            .setParameter("ativo", true)
            .setParameter("filial", filial)
            .setParameter("tipoCliente", tipoCliente)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_REGION, "CACHE_REGION_Cliente_todosClientesAtivosPesquisaAutoComplete");

    List<Cliente> resultList = null;
    try {
        resultList = query
                .setMaxResults(limite)
                .getResultList();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    return resultList;
```

O Problema é o seguinte, Tem dois Cliente que são iguais, menos o tipoCliente, que um é do tipo FILIAL, e o outro CLIENTE. Estou fazendo a query buscando pelo TipoCLiente.CLIENTE, e não pela filial, mas não sei o porque, por conta do like, vem junto nos resultados a filial tambem, se eu tirar os likes, vem somente o cliente do tipo CLIENTE. Tem alguma solução para isso ?

Comment: seu problema não está relacionado necessariamente aos likes, mas sim aos 'or' aparentemente, por favor dê mais detalhes de como estão seus dados e o que você está preenchendo nos parâmetros

Comment: Opa Lucaz beleza ? obrigado pela resposta, vou atualizar ali na postagem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu JPQL está com os `OR` sem os parenteses.

Verifique se este novo JPQL pode te ajudar:

```
SELECT c
FROM Cliente c
WHERE c.filial =:filial
    AND c.ativo =:ativo
    AND c.tipoCliente =:tipoCliente
    AND ( c.cnpj_cpf LIKE :cnpj_cpf_formatado
    OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( c.cnpj_cpf, '.', '' ),'/',''),'-','') LIKE  :cnpj_cpf
    OR c.razaoSocialNome LIKE :razaoSocialNome )
```